# SQL query from an existing list

Tags: sql

Sql newb so im trying to figure this out:

I pull a list of customer names that purchase a certain item:

```
select r.name
from records r
where r.item_purchased='apple'
```

Now I want to take that list of customers and pull the records for everything they have purchased, but I can't get past the errors. I've tried things like:

```
with customer_list as
(above)
select r.*
from records r
where r.name=customer_list
```

Comment: Can you show us what your table looks like?

Answer (score 2):

I believe a self join should solve your problem:

```
select distinct r2.*
from records r
join records r2
    on r2.name = r.name
where r.item_purchased='apple'
```

EDIT:  Added a `DISTINCT` based on @a_horse_with_no_name's insight into the difference between the results, because I doubt the duplication caused by the self join would be the desired result.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I have a large table that takes a considerable amount of time to query. Are there any differences in speed between the "join" and the "in" approach?

Comment: @johnjohnson: the IN solution and the JOIN do not necessarily return the same result.

Comment: @johnjohnson  I've added a `distinct` to my query... to eliminate possible duplicated results if a customer purchased multiple apples.  In my testing, the `DISTINCT + JOIN` produces the same execution plan as the `IN` query.... but the best way to know for sure would be to test both approaches against your data and look at the resulting execution plans.

Answer (score 2):

If you do want to use a CTE, this should work:

```
with customer_list as
(
  select r.name
  from records r
  where r.item_purchased='apple'
)
select r.*
from records r
where r.name in (select name from customer_list)
```

The difference between this and a JOIN (e.g. Michael's solution) is the join will produce a different result if the same customer purchased an apple more than once.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the potentially different results between the `JOIN` and the `IN`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select * from records where name in (
                       select name
                         from records 
                        where item_purchased='apple'
)
```